# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in JDBC program

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm making a simple JDBC program in java SE 7 but after compiling program it's giving "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgreasql.Driver" error i followed this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/ but not getting yet so please help.

Comment: please provide your code here?

Comment: You need to include the [postgres JDBC driver](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/) in the classpath.

Comment: Iren: here is my source code.. http://pastebin.com/iiSsSDPZ

Comment: perhaps because there is no postgr*ea*sql driver?

Comment: I believe its not a compile time error, but it occurs at runtime!

Comment: This is a runtime exception. Because if in compile time, the compiler says 'unknown symbol' on the methods of that class.

Comment: Removed the obsequious prelude...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

possibly you may not be setting the path of jdbc driver
follow the steps

1. Right click on your project
2. click buildpath->configure Build Path
3. click libraries tab
4. Click add external jars and give the path of driver

Comment: @AnubhavSharma which IDE you are using?

Comment: @SpringLearner You are the man ,it worked ,thank you

Comment: @sg28 you are welcome

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
org.postgreasql.Driver
```

should likely be

```
org.postgresql.Driver
```

Answer (score 1):

THe name of the driver is wrong also. Should be org.postgresql.Driver iso org.postgreasql.Driver. So maybe a typo in your java code where you do Class.forname()

Answer (score 1):

You would have to add the JAR file to your classpath for `org.postgresql.Driver`, You can download it from [HERE](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) .

Comment: i downloaded now how to set?

Comment: @AnubhavSharma See this [**LINK**](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)) to add jar file then clean and built (7 ways).

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the jdbc jar file on your build path. Firstly you have to download the jar from the link you provided. Then add it to build path.
If you use eclipse: Right click on your project at the package explorer->Configure Build Path->Libraries->Add external jar->select your jar.

Comment: The path is the location of your jar file. If you download it usually goes to Downloads folder or the file you chose to download files with browser.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your connection String url or connection driver and run code.