# using Eclipse for JDBC and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I'm trying to  install a couple of things so I can practice querying DB's with JDBC. But even with the copious amount of info I found through Google I'm not convinced I'm clear on what I need. It seems I need the Eclipse `SQL` Explorer plugin and `MySQL` 5.6 for `Windows`. Have I got that correct? And what about the `JDBC` Driver for `MySQL` (Connector/J) on the MySQL website?

Do I not need to worry about that when I'm using Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need the following things

1. [mysql database](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/)
2. [eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)
3. [mysql.jar](http://www.javaskool.com/jardownload/jarfiles/mysql.jar)
4. [jdk/jre](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Comment: I've downloaded MySQL 5.6 and extracted the files from the zip folder. I can't find any info on what I'm supposed to do with MySQL.jar when I've downloaded it though. What do I do with it?

Comment: you have to include it in the classpath

Comment: @acl77 see this to know how to jar files in class path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179687/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-in-jdbc-program